# How to recover a item from a XML tag

Tags: php, xml

I am stuck with getting the value from an XML element list. I wonder if someone here could help?

Here is the problem. I have this XML element:

```
<sequenceQuestion status="correct" maxPoints="10" maxAttempts="1" awardedPoints="10" usedAttempts="1">
  <direction>Order the following options</direction>
  <answers>
    <answer userDefinedPosition="0">Option 1</answer>
    <answer userDefinedPosition="1">Option 2</answer>
    <answer userDefinedPosition="2">Option 3</answer>
    <answer userDefinedPosition="3">Option 4</answer>
    <answer userDefinedPosition="4">Option 5</answer>
  </answers>
</sequenceQuestion>
```

I need to print the elements in the  tag. For example, I need to print "Option 1", "Option 2", ... , "Option 5" in a webpage by the order they were selected by the user.

If I use this code:

```
$SequenceQuestionNumber = 1;

foreach($answer_group->answers->answer as $userSequenceQuestion){

if($status!="notAnswered" && isset($userSequenceQuestion->attributes()->userDefinedPosition)) {
    $userDefinedPosition = (string)$userSequenceQuestion->attributes()->userDefinedPosition;
    $values .= "\"" . $userDefinedPosition . "\", ";
```

I get as answer values "0", "1", "2", "3" and "4". But what I need is not the 'userDefinedPosition" but rather the text associated with it. For "0" I need to print "Option 1", for "1" I need "Option 2", for "3" I need "Option 2", etc...

I have tried to build an array like this:

```
$answers = (array)$userSequenceQuestion->answer;
$values .= "\"" . $answers[$userDefinedPosition] . "\", ";
```

but I just get blanks (nothing) printed.

I guess what is messing my reference is the `userDefinedPosition` inside the  tag, but I am not sure on how to get the labels instead of the index numbers.

Comment: Does (string) $userSequenceQuestion; give you the value you want.

Comment: Hi BlargeMonster, Not sure I understood your question. I get "0", "1", ... when I use the $userDefinedPosition = (string)$userSequenceQuestion->attributes()->userDefinedPosition;  but what I need is "Option 1", "Option 2", etc...

Comment: `Xpath` is a cleaner solution instead of trying to re-invent the wheel

Comment: @JPMD so that what was BlargleMonster suggested, see what you get with `$userDefinedPosition = (string)$userSequenceQuestion;`, instead of the code in your comment..

Comment: @har07: Thanks, but If i use    $userDefinedPosition = (string)$userSequenceQuestion->attributes()->userDefinedPosition;    I get always the same order and not the order the student answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So I got it. Thank you all that contributed to an answer. This is the code which writes the user answer ordering:

```
if($answer_group->getName()=="sequenceQuestion") { //SEQUENCE QUESTION

$SequenceQuestionNumber = 1;

foreach($answer_group->answers->answer as $userSequenceQuestion){

if($status!="notAnswered" && isset($userSequenceQuestion->attributes()->userDefinedPosition)) {
$userDefinedPosition = (int)$userSequenceQuestion->attributes()->userDefinedPosition;
$answers = (string)$answer_group->answers->answer[$userDefinedPosition];
$values .= "\"" . $answers . "\", ";
} else {
$values .= "\"" . $status_notAnswered . "\", ";
}

$SequenceQuestionNumber++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do what you want to do with `Xpath` in a cleaner and more concise way like this

```
<?php

$string = <<<S
<sequenceQuestion status="correct" maxPoints="10" maxAttempts="1" awardedPoints="10" usedAttempts="1">
  <direction>Order the following options</direction>
  <answers>
    <answer userDefinedPosition="0">Option 1</answer>
    <answer userDefinedPosition="1">Option 2</answer>
    <answer userDefinedPosition="2">Option 3</answer>
    <answer userDefinedPosition="3">Option 4</answer>
    <answer userDefinedPosition="4">Option 5</answer>
  </answers>
</sequenceQuestion>
S;

$results = new SimpleXMLElement($string);

foreach ($results->xpath("answers")[0]->children() as $child) {
   echo $child . "<br />";

   }

?>
```

This outputs

```
Option 1
Option 2
Option 3
Option 4
Option 5
```

For more reference you can read the docs http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php

Comment: @ danidee: So I tried this code following your suggestion: 'code' if($status!="notAnswered" && isset($userSequenceQuestion->attributes()->userDefinedPosition)) {
        $userDefinedPosition = (string)$userSequenceQuestion->attributes()->userDefinedPosition;
        $results->xpath("answers")[0]->children() as $child;
        $values .= "\"" . $results . "\", ";
        //$values .= "\"" . $userDefinedPosition . "\", ";
       } else {
        $values .= "\"" . $status_notAnswered . "\", ";
       }   but i get nothing written. :-(

Comment: i really can't understand your code as it's jumbled up in the comment. but that doesn't look like you're fully using Xpath

Comment: Sorry, I am having trouble using the mini-markdown formating.  Lets see if i can get it wright now.    if($status!="notAnswered" && isset($userSequenceQuestion->attributes()->userDefinedPosition)) { $userDefinedPosition = (string)$userSequenceQuestion->attributes()->userDefinedPosition; $results->xpath("answers")[0]->children() as $child; $values .= "\"" . $results . "\", "; //$values .= "\"" . $userDefinedPosition . "\", "; } else { $values .= "\"" . $status_notAnswered . "\", "; }'

Comment: are you trying to print the tags with it like `<answer>Option 1</answer>`